# Incrementing over a URL variable

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, increment

```
import urllib2

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = 0
i = 1
data = []
while (i < 13):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(
        'http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?&slotCategoryId=4&scoringPeriodId=%d&seasonId=2018&startIndex=' % i, +str(x)).read(), 'html')
    tableStats = soup.find("table", ("class", "playerTableTable tableBody"))
    for row in tableStats.findAll('tr')[2:]:
        col = row.findAll('td')
        try:
            name = col[0].a.string.strip()
            opp = col[1].a.string.strip()
            rec = col[10].string.strip()
            yds = col[11].string.strip()
            dt = col[12].string.strip()
            pts = col[13].string.strip()
            data.append([name, opp, rec, yds, dt, pts])
        except Exception as e:
            pass
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=[
                      'PLAYER', 'OPP', 'REC', 'YDS', 'TD', 'PTS'])
    df
    i += 1
```

I have been working with a fantasy football program and I am trying to increment data over all weeks so I can create a dataframe for the top 40 players for each week.

I have been able to get it for any week of my choice by manually entering the week number in the `PeriodId` part of the url, but I am trying to programmatically increment it over each week to make it easier. I have tried using `PeriodId='+ I +'` and `PeriodId=%d` but I keep getting various errors about str and int concatenate and bad operands. Any suggestions or tips?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, it'd help to see the specific errors you get, as well as an example of a properly constructed URL. In your place, I'd first isolate the code constructing the URL I'm passing to urllib2 to check what's being produced.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the comma between `%i` and `str(x)` to concatenate the strings and see if that helps.

`soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?&slotCategoryId=4&scoringPeriodId=%d&seasonId=2018&startIndex='%i, +str(x)).read(), 'html')`

should be:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?&slotCategoryId=4&scoringPeriodId=%d&seasonId=2018&startIndex='%i +str(x)).read(), 'html')`

Answer (score 0):

if you have problem concatenating or formatting URL please create variable instead write it one line with `BeautifulSoup` and `urllib2.urlopen`.

Use parenthesis to format with multiple value like `"before %s is %s" % (1, 0)`

```
url = 'http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?&slotCategoryId=4&scoringPeriodId=%s&seasonId=2018&startIndex=%s' % (i, x)
# or
#url = 'http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?&slotCategoryId=4&scoringPeriodId=%s&seasonId=2018&startIndex=0' % i
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Make the code sorter will not effect the performance.